# When deploy github action "npm ERR! command sh -c" error raise

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, github-actions

I am using github actions, dockerfile to deploy container to AWS ecs.

But npm ERR is always raised after deploy task-definition to ECR.

I checked ECS container on EC2 instance with ssh. And I can API call in a few seconds but container stop soon.

I watched cloudwatch and find logs below.

I tried installing ts-node global, removing node_modules and npm cache... but error not disappear.

How to solve this? And where is the `2021-11-10T13_02_58_148Z-debug.log`? I can not find this on container...

```sh
npm ERR! path /test
2021-11-10T22:02:58.147+09:00   npm ERR! command failed
2021-11-10T22:02:58.147+09:00   npm ERR! signal SIGTERM
2021-11-10T22:02:58.147+09:00   npm ERR! command sh -c NODE_ENV=prod ts-node app.ts
2021-11-10T22:02:58.156+09:00   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-11-10T22:02:58.156+09:00   npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2021-11-10T13_02_58_148Z-debug.log
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "test-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "ajv": "^6.12.6",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1015.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "hardhat": "^2.6.6",
    "power-di": "^2.4.14",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=prod ts-node app.ts",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.22",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "mocha": "^9.1.3",
    "supertest": "^6.1.6"
  }
}
```

```
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN mkdir /test
WORKDIR /test 

COPY . /test

RUN npm update

RUN npm i

RUN npm i -g ganache-cli

RUN npm i -g ts-node

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

Comment: similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67851303/node-app-docker-image-runs-locally-and-fails-on-amazon-ecs